# Convert PRPS POSID to formatted WBS Element out of SAP

Tags: java, sql, sap-erp

I am looking a way for converting the `POSID` column from the `PRPS` table into a formatted WBS Element like SAP show us without SAP functions.

I have found the `TCJED` table to get masks and I've seen an ABAP function to made the conversion but I'm not comfortable with ABAP.

Does someone know how to use the masks from TCJED table ?

Sometimes there are some `0` at the end of POSID but they don't appear on the formatted WBS Element.

I want to do this in Java or in SQL.

Comment: removed ABAP tag as you want do this without ABAP, added Java and SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, here is the PL/SQL code :

mask come from tcjed table.
elementtoconvert is a raw WBS or raw Proj.

```
if (trim(mask) = '' or mask is null or trim(elementtoconvert) ='' or elementtoconvert is null) then 
            return elementToConvert;
        end if;
        select substring(elementToConvert, 1, currentPos) into wbs_Element_formated;
        select currentPos + 1 into currentPos;
        
        select string_to_array(substring(mask, 2, length(mask)-1),'-') into parts;
    
        for i in 1 .. array_upper(parts,1) loop
            select parts[i] like 'X%' into isXGroup;
            
            if (currentPos > length(elementToConvert)) then
                exit;
            end if;
        
            select currentPos + length(parts[i]) into endIndex;
            if (endIndex > length(elementToConvert)) then 
                select regexp_replace(substring(elementToConvert, currentPos), E'\\s+', '') into groupValue;
            else
                select regexp_replace(substring(elementToConvert, currentPos, length(parts[i])), E'\\s+', '') into groupValue;
            end if;
            
            if (isXGroup and length(parts[i]) > length(groupValue)) then
                select groupValue || Repeat(' ', length(parts[i]) - length(groupValue)) into groupValue;        
            end if;
            
            select currentPos + length(parts[i]) into currentPos;   
        
            if isXGroup = false then 
                if trim(groupValue) = '' then
                    continue;                       
                end if;
                if (groupValue ~* ('0{' || length(parts[i]) ||'}')) then
                    if(parts[array_upper(parts,1) -1] = parts[i]) then 
                        exit;
                    end if;
                    select trim(substring(elementToConvert, currentPos)) into nextChars;
                    if(nextChars = '' or nextChars ~* ('0{' || length(parts[i]) ||'}')) then
                        exit;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
            select wbs_Element_formated || '-' || groupValue into wbs_Element_formated;
        end loop;
        
        loop
            Exit when regexp_replace(wbs_Element_formated, E'\\s+$', '') not like '%-';
            select substring(wbs_Element_formated,1, length(wbs_Element_formated)-1)  into wbs_Element_formated;
        end loop;
        
        return trim(trailing ' ' from wbs_Element_formated);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call FM CONVERSION_EXIT_ABPSP_INPUT. This FM converts the internal format of POSID to the external format seen in Dynpros.

Comment: Yes I've seen this function in SAP but I access directly to raw data and I can't access to the sap functions. I want to write the same algorithm that SAP apply to convert the posid field.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program REPS_PSEXT_ID_CONV
"Convert Internal ID to External ID for Project and WBS Element"

that will store after SE38 execution the PRPS/PROJ external definition in table PSEXT_ID_CONV, field EXT_ID_CONV.

This program is used for Enterprise Search on HANA.

In the same package we find the BADIs WORKBREAKDOWN_UPDATE and PROJECTDEF_UPDATE where similar logic to REPS_PSEXT_ID_CONV can be applied and upsert done on commit in table PSEXT_ID_CONV.

To implement the BADI take also a look at OSS 2915621 - BADi WORKBREAKDOWN_UPDATE AT_SAVE not called.

In PS configuration (tcode /nspro ) we find also the badi's available/

[image]

Hope this help,

Cheers,